# how do you count unique factors and insert them into the same data frame in R

Tags: r

```
dput(x)

structure(list(State = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("Illinois", "Texas", "California", "Louisiana", 
"Michigan"), class = "factor"), Lat = structure(1:10, .Label = c("41.627", 
"41.85", "32.9588", "33.767", "33.0856", "30.4298", "29.7633", 
"42.4687", "43.0841", "29.6919"), class = "factor"), 
 Long = structure(1:10, .Label = c("-88.204", 
"-87.65", "-96.9812", "-118.1892", "-96.6115", "-90.8999", "-95.3633", 
"-83.5235", "-82.4905", "-95.6512"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("State", 
"Lat", "Long"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to have another column that says total which will be the total count of each State. I can do this by creating another column Total:

```
x$Total<-1
```

then

```
library(data.table
x<-data.table(x)
x<-x[,total:=sum(Total),by=State]
```

Is there a better/shorter/efficient way of counting factors in data frame?

Comment: Did you try `x<-x[,total:=.N,by=State]`? (No need to initialize `Total` first)

Comment: `tabulate(x$State)[x$State]` looks valid too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` like so (without having to create the `Total` column):

(Edit: thanks to @beginneR enlightening me to the existence of `n()`, this can be even more concise)

```
library('dplyr')
mutate(group_by(x, State), total = n())
```

@beginneR's solution of `group_by(x, State) %>% mutate(total = n())` is also good especially if you will need to go on to do other manipulations of your data. Similarly,

```
x %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  mutate(total = n())
```

will work, too.

Comment: I would propose to rewrite that to: `group_by(x, State) %>% mutate(total = n())`. (Note that you'd get a column named `sum(length(State))` in your example). Btw, `dplyr` also accepts `data.table`s to work on.

Comment: I've edited my answer to name the new column `total`. But I like @beginneR's solution better. I didn't know about `n()`, that's really handy!

Comment: @KaraWoo feel free to edit your question with `n()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use R base `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(.~State, FUN=length, data=x)
```